# Storing large JSON data in Postgres is infeasible, so what are the alternatives?

Tags: json, django, mongodb, postgresql, jsonb

I have large JSON data, greater than 2kB, in each record of my table and currently, these are being stored in JSONB field. 
My tech stack is Django and Postgres.
I don't perform any updates/modifications on this json data but i do need to read it, frequently and fast. However, due to the JSON data being larger than 2kB, Postgres splits it into chunks and puts it into the TOAST table, and hence the read process has become very slow.
So what are the alternatives? Should i use another database like MongoDB to store these large JSON data fields?
Note: I don't want to pull the keys out from this JSON and turn them into columns. This data comes from an API.

Comment: Your alternatives will depend on the context. Maybe store it relationally, instead of as JSON?

Comment: I can likely provide an answer if you can give a little more detail: Roughly how many rows do you have? Roughly how big are the JSON blobs? Do you need to fetch all the JSON back or just part of it? Are you querying against values in the JSON? What do you know of your database server's hardware (is it shared/dedicated, how much memory, does it run on SSDs etc)?

Comment: I believe the issue is not with the JSONB field, but with the data, or row being larger than 2kB, causing the data to be stored outside the row. @ResonateAlpha, have you tried compressing the data in other ways? Personally I prefer to keep things in one persistent storage solution, then use some in memory data structure (like Redis) to cache the data for high performance reads. That way, your platform is not dependent on multiple points of failure (e.g. if mongodb crashes, your system fails, whereas if Redis fails, your site will just run slower).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response guys. I am using this table to store the responses ( JSON data ) from various apis that are continually being hit by the server. So the table keeps growing in size as more and more times the api are hit. Now, if someone decides to hit the same api (say, after a week) with the same arguments and i know that the response will be the same (i know when the response will change via some webhook), i will use this db to read the json and send it back to the requestor.

Comment: I don't want to store this relationally because each api has a different kind of response and some keys might not always be present in each and every response. I need to store this data as json only.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for the claim that it is infeasible?  While TOAST certainly has some overhead, it is generally not very large.  If you have found a pathological case, you will have to share it with us to get any meaningful help.

Comment: Hi, you can go through these stackoverflow questions to get the idea of the problem i am going through.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214221/selecting-from-jsonb-field-slow
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182848/slow-access-to-jsonb-column

For the evidence, you can generate a random dataset with a json field where each record has more than 2kb json data in a single field. You can then call `select *` on this table and you will notice the difference in time compared to calling `select *` on a table where all the corresponding json keys are columns.

Comment: From what you say above it sounds to me like you're using postgres as a caching layer (perhaps amongst other other things). I think there are better options available for caching restful API responses. If you need an application-level cache then something like Redis or memcache could work. You could also put a cache such as nginx or squid in front of your application. I think we need you to really spell out use-case in detail in order for us to say more.

Comment: The use case is that i don't want to refetch the data that i know hasn't changed on the third party apis. 
There are apis for getting various details about a customer such as their call history, email history, location history, etc. and i know via a webhook which of these has changed and so i mark this data as outdated. Now, if my server gets a request to fetch a customer's data, i will make the request to the api for only the outdated data and rest will be fetched from the database only and then i will also update the outdated data.

Comment: I don't want to use a cache because i want this data to be persistent and its very big. Caches are expensive and so its not an option.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to answer specifically without knowing the details of your situation, but here are some things you may try:

1. Use Postgres 12 (stored) [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) to maintain the fields or smaller JSON blobs that are commonly needed. This adds storage overhead, but frees you from having to maintain this duplication yourself.
2. [Create indexes for any JSON fields](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) you are querying (Postgresql allows you to create indexes for JSON expressions).
3. Use a [composite index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html), where the first field in the index the field you are querying on, and the second field (/json expression) is that value you wish to retrieve. In this case Postgresql should retrieve the value from the index.
4. Similar to 1, create a [materialised view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) which extracts the fields you need and allows you to query them quickly. You can add indexes to the materialised view too. This may be a good solution as materialised views can be slow to update, but in your case your data doesn't update anyway.
5. Investigate why the toast tables are being slow. I'm not sure what performance you are seeing, but if you really do need to pull back a lot of data then you are going to need fast data access whatever database you choose to go with.

Your mileage may vary with all of the above suggestions, especially as each will depend on your particular use case. (see the questions in my comment)

However, the overall idea is to use the tools that Postgresql provides to make your data quickly accessible. Yes this may involve pulling the data out of its original JSON blob, but this doesn't need to be done manually. Postgresql provides some great tools for this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't know how materialized view works, so i will give it a try.

Comment: No worries. I realised from your above responses that while you are not updating rows, you are inserting rows. Your materialised view will need to be refreshed before the newly inserted rows will appear in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to store and read fully this json object without using the json structure in your WHERE query, what about simply storing this data as binary in a `bytea` column? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html